# Trigger the rescan of MediaStore programmatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mediascanner

Notice that the newly added photos(copied over using "adb push" into Pictures folder) are not included in the MediaStore Content Provider. Is there a way to trigger the rescan programmatically?

Already tried:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())));
```

and

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures")));
```

which seem not work.

The broadcast `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` cannot be used after Android 4.4.

(1) Other than using MediaScannerWrapper to scan files myself, is there other way to programmatically trigger the rescan?

(2) Under what circumstances will the rescan happen in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Already tried

You are passing a directory, not a file.

> is there other way to programatically trigger the rescan?

Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method. This too requires a file AFAIK.

Comment: I am using a MediaScannerWrapper to implement MediaScannerConnectionClient to scan though the whole directory which can be very expensive. Is there a way more efficient? like just trigger the database to rescan for new files?

Comment: @Phi: "Is there a way more efficient?" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: @ CommonsWare: Thank you, and under what circumstances other than reboot will trigger the rescan of MediaStore?

Comment: @Phi: AFAIK, that's up to the device manufacturer. Usually, adding or ejecting removable media triggers an indexing of at least that removable media. And, I get the impression that a scan happens periodically on its own accord, but I do not know how frequently.